# Add to Roster using xmpppy?

Tags: python, xmpp, messaging, xmpppy

I'm trying to add a JID to my Roster with XMPPpy, but nothing I've tried has worked. Their website barely has any documentation, and what they do have has literally no examples, so most of what I've been doing is just guesswork. I've tried their "Subscribe" and "Authorize" functions. Even tried their "setItem" function, and literally nothing has worked. Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381597/xmpp-chat-accessing-contacts-status-messages-with-xmpppys-roster and http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/xmpp.roster.Roster-class.html